# Spark on YARN - Submiting Spark jobs from Django

Tags: django, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am developing a web app with the following components :

- Apache Spark running on a Cluster with 3 nodes (spark 1.4.0, hadoop 2.4 and YARN)
- Django Web App server

The Django app will create 'on demand' spark jobs (they can be concurrent jobs, depending of how many users are using the app)

I would to know if there is any way to submit spark jobs from the python code in Django? can i integrate pyspark in django? or Maybe can i call the YARN API directly to submit jobs?

I know that i can submit jobs to the cluster using the spark-submit script, but i'm trying to avoid using it. (because it would have to be a shell command execution from the code, and is not very safe to do it)

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

JG

Answer (score 2):

A partial, untested answer: Django is a web framework, so it's difficult to manage long jobs (more than 30sec), which is probably the case for your spark jobs.

So you'll need a asynchronous job queue, such as celery. It's a bit of a pain (not that bad but still), but I would advise you to start with that.

You would then have :

- Django to launch/monitor jobs
- rabbitMQ/celery asynchronous job queue
- custom celery tasks, using pySpark and launching sparks

Answer (score 0):

There's a project on github called Ooyala's job server:
https://github.com/ooyala/spark-jobserver.

This allows you to submit spark jobs to YARN via HTTP request.

In Spark 1.4.0+ support was added to monitor job status via HTTP request as well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.